# シェーダーのtexture情報から頂点を動かす方法について

Tags: unity3d

unityのshaderをいろいろ学んでいるのですが、相談できる方もいなく、そして悪戦苦闘しており、ここに投稿させて頂きましたm(_ _)m

■質問
シェーダーにて、ノイズ系のtexture情報を取得→そこからvertexを操作する方法を知りたいです、

というのも、下記記事のように、ノイズ系のtextureをはりつけて、明度の違いからplaneを凹凸したくて…

この記事にあるhader graphでの作り方は理解できるのですが、pgだけだったらどう表現するのか１日かけてggってもわからず…
https://marunouchi-tech.i-studio.co.jp/5289/

誰かご教授いただけると本当に嬉しいですm(_ _)m

Comment: 「pgだけ」＝プログラムだけ という意味でしょうか？ご自身にしかわからない略語は避けたほうがよいです。

Comment: 大変失礼しました。プログラマという意味で使いました。
Displacementと判明したので、こちら質問を終わらせて頂きます。